# How to get lower cutoff frequency?

Tags: amplifier, cutoff-frequency

These are the equations for finding lower cutoff frequencies for a BJT common emitter amplifier:
[image]

In finding the cutoff frequency, capacitor impedance must match the resistance so that output voltage from the resistor is Vout/sqrt2(half-power) .

However, why is that: $$f_B=\frac{1}{2\pi(R_s+R_{in} ) C_{C1} }$$
[image]
As illustrated above, Vout depends on the voltage drop on R_in only **and not on R_s(or R_g)**. The voltage drop on R_s is wasted just like the drop on the impedance of the input coupling capacitor. Then why is that X_c must match the R_s+R_in if Vout only depends on R_in?

If X_c must match R_s + R_in, then Vout at R_s+R_in at cutoff frequency is Vout/sqrt(2) **BUT that is the drop on BOTH R_s and R_in, the drop at R_in(where we are getting the output voltage for the base of transistor) is less than Vout/sqrt(2).** This means the cutoff frequency is not right.

I can also say the same thing on the lower cutoff formula for the collector capacitor in which R_l is added to R_c BUT output voltage ONLY DEPENDS ON R_l(load resistor). If I use that formula, then the output voltage at load resistor will not be Vout/sqrt(2) since some of the voltage will also drop at R_c.... (I understood that at this part, I need first to convert the Norton current to thevenin so that R_c will be in series with R_l)

The book and the site says the same thing but I don't know what am I getting wrong here

Source: https://wps.prenhall.com/chet_paynter_introduct_6/0,5779,426214-,00.html

Comment: *Vout depends on the voltage drop on R_in only and not on R_s* So you're saying that if we change the value or \$R_S\$ or \$R_G\$ then \$V_{out}\$ doesn't change? Is that really true? Think about a voltage divider and think what happens to the signal **current** when \$R_S\$ or \$R_G\$ when their values change. Next step, the impedance \$X_C\$ of \$C_{in}\$ is in series with \$R_G\$, what can you conclude from that?

Comment: Yes, changing Rs will change Vout. But, what I'm trying to say is that output voltage is only at R_in and not on R_s. If I use the cutoff frequency using that formula, the voltage drop at R_in will be less than Vout/sqrt(2). **It will only equal Vout/sqrt(2) if I add the voltage drop at both R_in and Rs**

Comment: I'm not getting your point and don't see the need for sqrt(2) so let me explain it in another way, this applies to the 2nd picture in your question: 1) \$I_{sig}\$ is the signal current: \$I_{sig} = V_G / (R_G + X_{Cin} + R_{in})\$ 2) then \$V_{out} = R_{in} *I_{sig}\$ 3) the **cutoff frequency** is defined as the point where the signal is **halved** compared to the passband transfer. This circuit is a **highpass** filter, at high frequencies \$X_{Cin}\$ is **zero**. So \$I_{sig} = V_G / (R_G + 0 + R_{in})\$.

Comment: At the cutoff frequency, that current will be **halved**. *How do we **halve** that current?* By lowering the frequency such that the term \$(R_G + X_{Cin} + R_{in})\$ doubles. We can only influence \$X_{Cin}\$ so \$X_{Cin} = R_G + R_{in}\$ and that is what is shown in the formula.

Comment: Cut-off frequency is when current is at half? But I read its the half-power frequency(not half-current) that's why I said Vout/sqrt(2) must be the resulting voltage when frequency is at cut-off so that resulting power is 1/2. Also, correct me pls, But I notice that if current is at half, then voltage will also be half, then the resulting power will be 1/4 of the max power(not 1/2)

Comment: Cutoff doesn't only deal with power, you're looking at a voltage \$V_{out}\$ so the power is irrelevant. To complicate things there's also Real and Imaginary parts of the power. I suggest that you refer back to the simplest example, an RC lowpass filter: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html